# How to access Objective C obfuscated class from swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a project where I used both, Objective C and Swift.
From security reasons, for some classes and methods written in Objective C I used obfuscation.

This is my code:

```
#ifndef AccessManager_h

#define AccessManager ySbIXoscpewLLSwVacDpZvPvQeNDtG
#define loginWithUsername TEWhYyXaCdGrCViPbZZHWXoBiUPvPn

#endif

@interface AccessManager : AFHTTPSessionManager

-(void)loginWithUsername:(NSString*)username password:(NSString*)password success:(WSSuccessBlock)success failure:(WSFailureBlock)failure;

@end
```

And this is my swift code that tried to access the obfuscated class

```
AccessManager.instance().login(withUsername: "my_user", password: "password", success: { (response) in
        //TODO
    }) { (error) in
        //TODO
    }
```

And this is the error that I get when I build the project

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AccessManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MySwiftClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can access an Objective C class that is obfuscated from Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Macros you have changed the name of the class and the method name. This is an easy way to perform obfuscation.

But, that would also break the Swift-Objective-C interoperability if you try to use original class name and its methods.

You can of-course still use your obj-c class by the redefined names in a Swift class(changed the block params to simple BOOLs for simplicity):

```
let accessManager = ySbIXoscpewLLSwVacDpZvPvQeNDtG()
accessManager.teWhYyXaCdGrCViPbZZHWXoBiUPvPn("", password: "", success: true, failure: true)
```

Comment: But there is any solution to use loginWithUsername instead teWhYyXaCdGrCViPbZZHWXoBiUPvPn for method name?

Comment: @user2576008: I dont think so 

Comment: Perhaps you can implement some sort of interface on the Objective-C side that passes the needed class and instance objects to the Swift side, so it does not need to know the actual (runtime) class names.

Comment: As long as the helper methods that pass classes over to Swift code are implemented as C functions (_not_ Objective-C methods), their function names will not remain on the binary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use preprocessor like -

```
#define ABC DEF
```

where DEF is a Class name.
You need to import this file in your bridging header and then define it as below:

typedef DEF* ABC;

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528183/reference-class-definition-from-prefix-header-in-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Swift is not able to understand the type of the defined preprocessor which is why you are not able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is very basic example, but gives an idea of what you can do:

Provide an interface to your class and method's runtime representations, by means of global C-functions that are callable from Swift code.

Unlike Objective-C methods, which use dynamic dispatch and whose names thus  survive into the binary as plain strings (selectors), C function calls are compiled into jump instructions to the appropriate memory address; the function name is not present in the binary for hackers to decompile/inspect.

---

**AccessManager.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#ifndef AccessManager_h
#define AccessManager ySbIXoscpewLLSwVacDpZvPvQeNDtG
#define loginWithUsername TEWhYyXaCdGrCViPbZZHWXoBiUPvPn
#endif

/// Provides the class object at runtime
Class accessManagerClass();

/// Provides the method name at runtime
SEL loginMethodName();

@interface AccessManager : NSObject

- (instancetype) init;
- (void) loginWithUsername:(NSString*) userName;

@end
```

**AccessManager.m:**

```
#import "AccessManager.h"

Class accessManagerClass() {
    return [AccessManager self];
}

SEL loginMethodName() {
    return @selector(loginWithUsername:);
}

@implementation AccessManager

- (void) loginWithUsername:(NSString*) userName {
    // Dummy implementation, for demonstration purposes:
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
    NSLog(userName);
}

@end
```

**Bridging Header:**

```
#import "AccessManager.h"
```

**ViewController.swift (most of the class omitted):**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let managerClass: AnyClass = accessManagerClass(), let methodName = loginMethodName() {

        // Instantiate the manager from the class:
        let manager = (managerClass as! NSObject.Type).init()

        // (I'm still a bit fuzzy about metatypes on Swift,
        //  perhaps the line above can be improved)

        // Call the obfuscated method: 
        manager.perform(methodName, with: "AAAA")
    }
}
```

When run, it prints:

```
% -[ySbIXoscpewLLSwVacDpZvPvQeNDtG TEWhYyXaCdGrCViPbZZHWXoBiUPvPn:]
% AAAA
```

...which proves that:

1. Class and method name are obfuscated at runtime.
2. The method is actually called

I put a **sample project** with all the code above [on GitHub](https://github.com/nicolas-miari/Obfuscation-Demo).