# iOS: How can I use #define from Objective-C in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, constants

I use a Constants.h file in Objective-C that contains #define and I would like to use it in Swift 3.0. Do you think it is possible?

I have different type, for example:

```
/*int*/        #define EVENT_ID         12
/*Class name*/ #define FORM_TO_USE      RegistrationForm_xxxx_xxx
/*String*/    #define name             @"name1"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this answer by me to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361384/433373

Comment: In your particular case, perhaps abandon the use of `#define` constants and use actual global variables, e.g. `int EVENT_ID = 12;` in the implementation file, and `extern int EVENT_ID;` in the header, etc.

Comment: I checked but the thing is I would like to know if it is possible to use EVENT_ID in my example directly in Swift (as in objective-C) instead of writing 12. I would like to have a generic solution.

Comment: @Claudio yes. like this #define DB_Name "test.sqlite"

Comment: You can still use it as `EVENT_ID` everywhere. You just need to define it as **an actual variable** instead of a compile-time text-replacement rule :)

Comment: @Nicolas MiariI understand, but that Constants.h file contains next to 10 000 #define, and if there is a solution to create a type of "bridge" ans using it directly in Swift, it should be very cool :D

Comment: I'm posting an answer. Give me a second

Comment: @Dixit Akabari But my problem is even if I put it in the Constants.h, I cannot see that in a .swift file

Comment: You **can** see them if you `#include` the header file in your **Bridging Header**.

Comment: @Claudio your Constants.h file add in "objective c bridging header" in build settings.

Answer (score 2):

Best Practice for Swift Constants -

**Constants.swift**

```
struct Constants {
    static let someValue = "TEST"
    static let arrayOfTests: [String] = ["foo", "bar", someValue]
}

struct Event {
    static let id = 12
    static let name = "event Name"
}
struct NotificationKey {
    static let welcome = "event Name"
}
```

**Use:**

```
let eventID  = Event.id
let eventName = Event.name
let aValue = Constants.someValue
let notification = NotificationKey.welcome
```

Answer (score 1):

In simple case we can use bridging header and import constant.h file and use EVENT_ID  directly in code , this should work.

Comment: seems like it doesn't work

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead

`let EVENT_ID = 12 
let FORM_TO_USE =  RegistrationForm_xxxx_xxx 
let name = name1`